# I want to make service which broadcast notification if I am in geo-fence or Not

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-geofence

```
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
```

this is ray casting algo checking current user loction lies within the points or not

```
            if (PolyUtil.containsLocation(latLngchangeloc, arrayPoints, true)==true) {
                //Intent intent=new Intent();
                //intent.setAction("MyBroadcast");
                //intent.putExtra("values","enter");
                //sendBroadcast(intent);
               // sendNotification("enter");
                //Toast.makeText(this, "enter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                //Intent intent=new Intent();
                //intent.setAction("MyBroadcast");
                //intent.putExtra("values","leave");
               //sendBroadcast(intent);
               // sendNotification("leave");
                //Toast.makeText(this, "leave", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
            h.postDelayed(this, 3000);
        }
    }, delay);


}
```

This is working fine, checking current location in geo-fence.
Now I want to make it as service so it broadcast message when I enter that geo-fence or not. I am making custom fence for this.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me for geofencing you can also try it.

On map click you can add a marker like :

```
 @Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
    markerForGeofence(latLng);
}

private Marker geoFenceMarker;

//create marker for geo fence
private void markerForGeofence(LatLng model) {
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(model)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));

    if ( map!=null ) {
        if (geoFenceMarker != null)
            geoFenceMarker.remove();

        geoFenceMarker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }
}
```

start geofencing around this marker:

```
// Start Geofence creation process
private void startGeofence() {
    if( geoFenceMarker != null ) {
        Geofence geofence = createGeofence( geoFenceMarker.getPosition(), GEOFENCE_RADIUS );
        GeofencingRequest geofenceRequest = createGeofenceRequest( geofence );
        addGeofence( geofenceRequest );
    }
}


private static final long GEO_DURATION = 60 * 60 * 1000;
private static final String GEOFENCE_REQ_ID = "firstGeoFence";
private static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS = 2000.0f; // in meters

// Create a Geofence Request
private GeofencingRequest createGeofenceRequest(Geofence geofence ) {
    return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
            .setInitialTrigger( GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER )
            .addGeofence( geofence )
            .build();
}

// Create a Geo fence
private Geofence createGeofence(LatLng latLng, float radius ) {
    return new Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId(GEOFENCE_REQ_ID)
            .setCircularRegion( latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, radius)
            .setExpirationDuration( GEO_DURATION )
            .setTransitionTypes( Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                    | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT )
            .build();
}

public void addGeofence(GeofencingRequest request) {
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                request,
                createGeofencePendingIntent()
        ).setResultCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void onResult(@NonNull Result result) {
    if ( result.getStatus().isSuccess() ) {
        drawGeofence();
    }
}

private final int GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE = 0;

private PendingIntent createGeofencePendingIntent() {
        if ( geoFencePendingIntent != null )
            return geoFencePendingIntent;

        Intent intent = new Intent( this, GeofenceTrasitionService.class);
        return PendingIntent.getService(
                this, GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
}
```

draw circle on google map:

```
    // Draw Geofence circle on GoogleMap
private Circle geoFenceLimits;
private void drawGeofence() {
    if ( geoFenceLimits != null )
        geoFenceLimits.remove();

    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
            .center( geoFenceMarker.getPosition())
            .strokeColor(Color.argb(50, 70,70,70))
            .fillColor( Color.argb(100, 150,150,150) )
            .radius( GEOFENCE_RADIUS );
    geoFenceLimits = map.addCircle( circleOptions );
}
```

you also have to implement ResultCallback in activity which will override onResult method

This class will handle notification :

```
public class GeofenceTrasitionService extends IntentService {

private static final String TAG = GeofenceTrasitionService.class.getSimpleName();
public static final int GEOFENCE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;

public GeofenceTrasitionService() {
    super(TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Retrieve the Geofencing intent
    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);

    // Handling errors
    if ( geofencingEvent.hasError() ) {
        String errorMsg = getErrorString(geofencingEvent.getErrorCode() );
        return;
    }

    // Retrieve GeofenceTrasition
    int geoFenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
    // Check if the transition type
    if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
            geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT ) {
        // Get the geofence that were triggered
        List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();
        // Create a detail message with Geofences received
        String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTrasitionDetails(geoFenceTransition, triggeringGeofences );
        // Send notification details as a String
        sendNotification( geofenceTransitionDetails );
    }
}

// Create a detail message with Geofences received
private String getGeofenceTrasitionDetails(int geoFenceTransition, List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {
    // get the ID of each geofence triggered
    ArrayList<String> triggeringGeofencesList = new ArrayList<>();
    for ( Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences ) {
        triggeringGeofencesList.add( geofence.getRequestId() );
    }

    String status = null;
    if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER )
        status = "Entering ";
    else if ( geoFenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT )
        status = "Exiting ";
    return status + TextUtils.join( ", ", triggeringGeofencesList);
}

// Send a notification
private void sendNotification( String msg ) {
    // Intent to start the main Activity

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MapActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Creating and sending Notification
    NotificationManager notificatioMng =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
    notificatioMng.notify(
            GEOFENCE_NOTIFICATION_ID,
            createNotification(msg, notificationPendingIntent));
}

// Create a notification
private Notification createNotification(String msg, PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setColor(Color.RED)
            .setContentTitle(msg)
            .setContentText("Geofence Notification!")
            .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    return notificationBuilder.build();
}

// Handle errors
private static String getErrorString(int errorCode) {
    switch (errorCode) {
        case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE:
            return "GeoFence not available";
        case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES:
            return "Too many GeoFences";
        case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS:
            return "Too many pending intents";
        default:
            return "Unknown error.";
    }
}
}
```

In manifest file:

```
<service android:name="com.jaspreet.mapdemo.geoFence.GeofenceTrasitionService" />
```

Comment: i understand this.but i want to check that current location of user is in geofence or not..this is i want to do in services and then user get notify that he is in geofence or not..remember i am creating geofence by marking points on map and then checking user is in geofence or not through ray casting algoo... .

Comment: what you can do, you can add a marker on map click and start geofencing around this location by creating a createGeofence area.

Comment: @DaniyalIrfan check new answer  !!

Comment: yes bro i know that way of doing geofence .but my requirement is to create geofence on runtime of any shape on map .not only in circle so thats why i have to implement each and eavery thing on mmy own ..